# Open Menu Bar app on launch (Mac OS App) [Swift, ViewController opening on launch]

Tags: swift, macos, button, storyboard

I need to be able to have the Menu Bar app open when it is launched. I am currently using `button.performClick(nil)` and it sort of works but it launches the viewController on the wrong screen/way off the screen.

So what is the best way to have the ViewController pop up on launch.

So basically I want this window to open on launch
[LINK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i308O.jpg)

Comment: It appears we're working on similar things. I am using statusItem?.button?.performClick(nil) to open my app. I am not putting it in as an answer because I am having problems with it. Once the window is displayed, no code runs again until the window closes and then it works again. My statusItem is an NSStatusItem with an NSMenuItem & NSMenu.

Comment: @AppDever thanks for the reply. It does seem like we are working on similar things. I use this to open the app: ```if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.performClick(nil)
        }```.
Problem is on first launch it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/ZIoMEBd.png
Then once you close the window and reopen it, it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/UcvxGI9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a simple and dirty workaround for my issue.

I had this code: (BEFORE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpVCj.png)

```
if let button = statusItem.button {
     button.performClick(nil)
}
```

But then I added a .5 second timer and it fixed all my issues (you could probably get away with a .1 second timer): (AFTER https://i.stack.imgur.com/RamDf.png)

```
if let button = statusItem.button {
          _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.5, repeats: false) { (timer) in
               button.performClick(nil)
     }
}
```

Note: Images are purely for visual aid